# How to execute DDL statement in a different schema?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, metadata, ddl

I'd like to execute a DDL statement (for example: `create table test(id int, str varchar)`) in different DB schemas.

In order to execute this DDL i was going to use the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy import DDL, text, create_engine

engine = create_engine(...)

ddl_cmd = "create table test(id int, str varchar)"

DDL(ddl_cmd).execute(bind=engine)
```

How can I specify in which DB schema to execute this DDL statement, **not changing the DDL command itself**?

I don't understand why such a basic parameter like `schema` is missing in the `DDL().execute()` method. I guess I'm missing some important concept, but I couldn't figure it out.

---

**UPD:** I've found the ["schema_translate_map" execution option](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#schema-translating), but it didn't work for me - the table will be still created in the default schema.

Here are my attempts:

```
conn = engine.connect().execution_options(schema_translate_map={None: "my_schema"})
```

then i tried different variants:

```
# variant 1
conn.execute(ddl_cmd)
# variant 2
conn.execution_options(schema_translate_map={None: "my_schema"}).execute()
# variant 3
DDL(ddl_cmd).compile(bind=conn).execute()
# variant 4
DDL(ddl_cmd).compile(bind=conn).execution_options(schema_translate_map={None: "my_schema"})
```

but every time the table will be created in the default schema. :(

Comment: You might consider using Core to build the DDL for you. Example [here](https://pastebin.com/uRrxSbbn).

Comment: @GordThompson, thank you for the advise! In this project i'm going to get multiple different DDL statements (CREATE|ALTER|DROP: table, index, view, trigger, etc, ) and execute them in different DBs (Oracle, MySQL, Redshift, etc.), so I can't rewrite them all. Do you have an idea how to set or map the schema when i'm dealing with plain SQL / DDL statements? I've tried to use the ["schema_translate_map" execution option](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/changelog/migration_11.html#multi-tenancy-schema-translation-for-table-objects), but it didn't work for (please see updated question).

Comment: @GordThompson, do you know any workaround? Is there a way to compile a DDL/SQL statement and to map/replace the schema?

Comment: "multiple different DDL statements … and execute them in different DBs" - The primary purpose of the "SQL Expression Language" in Core is to help you do precisely what you've described.

Comment: @GordThompson, frankly speaking i don't understand - how may I use `"SQL Expression Language" in Core` when i'm receiving plain SQL / DDL statements as text. Could you please write an answer with a small example ?

Comment: "plain SQL / DDL statements as text" are almost certainly not going to be cross-platform anyway. Even something as simple as `CREATE TABLE table1 (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, txt varchar(50) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id))
` is valid for MySQL but not for MSSQL.

Comment: @MaxU Whether you're still looking for an answer? ;)